# How do i get the value from radio button and use it inside a url

Tags: vuejs2

all. I want to have some knowledge on how do i fetch a value from the radio button and use that inside a url
Here is the code:
HTML

```
  <b-form-radio name="radio" v-model="selectedAge" value="30">
     Hub
  </b-form-radio>
  <b-form-radio name="radio" v-model="selectedAge" value="40">
     Point
  </b-form-radio>
  <button href="localhost/test/exam/names?age={selectedAge}"></button>
```

SCRIPT

```
 data () {
      return {
        selectedAge: '',
      }
    }
```

I am not able to get the value from the radio button here. Please advise
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following ......

```js
var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      methods: {
          onChange(event) {
              var data = event.target.value;
              console.log(data);
              document.getElementById('btn_1').href = 'localhost/test/exam/names?age=' + data;
          }
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <b-form-radio name="radio" v-model="selectedAge" @change="onChange($event)" value="30">
    Hub
  </b-form-radio>
  <b-form-radio name="radio" v-model="selectedAge" @change="onChange($event)" value="40">
    Point
  </b-form-radio>
  <br />
  <a id="btn_1" href="localhost/test/exam/names?age={selectedAge}">Button</a>
</div>
```